# What is the translation of the Brihat Parashar Hora Shastram (1932 edition)?

Tags: astrology, translation-request, brihat-parashara-hora-shastra

Help translate into English **chapter 47, verse 26** — Brihat Parashar Hora Shastram Uttara Khand Khemraj 1932 Shri Krishna Museum Kurukshetra

> देहायासो मनस्तापो राजद्वारे विरोधकृत ॥ विदेशगमनं चैव तीथयात्रादिकं फलम्‌

> dehāyāso manastāpo rājadvāre virodhakṛta || videśagamanaṃ caiva tīthayātrādikaṃ phalam‌

Comment: "Physical exertion and mental anguish are the causes of opposition at the gate of the king. Going abroad is also the fruit of pilgrimage . "

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the page](https://ia600700.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/22/items/BrihatParasharHoraShastramUttaraKhandKhemraj1932ShriKrishnaMuseumKurukshetra/Brihat%20Parashar%20Hora%20Shastram%20Uttara%20Khand%20Khemraj%201932%20-%20Shri%20Krishna%20Museum%20Kurukshetra_jp2.zip&file=Brihat%20Parashar%20Hora%20Shastram%20Uttara%20Khand%20Khemraj%201932%20-%20Shri%20Krishna%20Museum%20Kurukshetra_jp2/Brihat%20Parashar%20Hora%20Shastram%20Uttara%20Khand%20Khemraj%201932%20-%20Shri%20Krishna%20Museum%20Kurukshetra_0437.jp2&id=BrihatParasharHoraShastramUttaraKhandKhemraj1932ShriKrishnaMuseumKurukshetra&scale=8&rotate=0) you need in this book. It states that the aspects of Rahu are similar to those of Jupiter.

Comment: The book he shared has a different verse at that number, so this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue which 47th chapter 26th verse are you taking about?? Can you please add a snap of it. I tried to search it in the English and Hindi translations. No similar verse is found.

In the link you have given I found it [here](https://archive.org/details/BrihatParasharHoraShastramUttaraKhandKhemraj1932ShriKrishnaMuseumKurukshetra/page/n365/mode/1up?view=theater), you can see the chapter is 47 and the 26th verse.

[image]

But I found two translations of English and Hindi, which has two different verses at 47tu chapter and 26th shloka

[English Translation](https://www.pdfdrive.com/brihat-parashar-hora-shastram-translation-by-santhanam-vol-2-e42049331.html): Page 89-90

[image]

---

[Hindi Translation](https://archive.org/details/brihat-parashar-hora-shastra-vol-2-suresh-chandra-mishra/page/466/mode/1up?view=theater)

[image]